# Spring boot web socket handler not working with @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-annotations, java-websocket

I am trying to create a websocket client in spring boot. I have used WebsocketConnectionmanager to create client with handler but I noticed that the service with @Autowired annotation does not get created and the exception "messageService is null" is thrown. Given below are the files:

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public WebSocketConnectionManager instrumentsWsConnectionManager() {
        return getWebSocketConnectionManager(environment.getProperty("wsconfig.uri-prefix") + environment.getProperty("wsconfig.message-uri"), new MessageWsHandler());
    }

    privateWebSocketConnectionManager getWebSocketConnectionManager(String webSocketUri, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler)
    {
        //Generates a web socket connection
        WebSocketConnectionManager manager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(
                new StandardWebSocketClient(),
                webSocketHandler, //Must be defined to handle messages
                webSocketUri);

        //Will connect as soon as possible
        manager.setAutoStartup(true);

        return manager;
    }
}
```

**MessageWsHandler.java**

```
@Component
public class MessageWsHandlerimplements WebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    MessageService messageService;

    // Additional code
```

**MessageService.java**

```
@Service
public class MessageService {

// Service code

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: That worked, I had created an instance of a message handler using "new" operator instead of Autowiring it.